# Depleted uranium shells in the Russian nuclear doctrine

Tags: russian-federation, nuclear-weapons

According to the current nuclear doctrine of Russia, is the transfer/usage of shells containing depleted uranium considered as a nuclear attack on Russia? Technologically, can it be considered as a radiological weapon or dirty bomb? I am not interested in what Putin or Medvedev say on the TV, but the official Russian doctrine. Is any specific countermeasure for such a weapon mentioned in it? If they interpret it as an attack with a dirty bomb, let's say, via a political decision, what are the countermeasures according to the doctrine?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I clarified the question. Nevertheless, I think this is an important part. If they consider it as a dirty bomb, then the countermeasures for a dirty bomb in the doctrine should be/might be activated. Depending on the answer to the second question, such an interpretation can of course be a political decision of Putin.

Comment: Asking us to *speculate* on what their response will be is off limit.  But they can't *privately* consider it to be a dirty bomb, unless they count their own doctrine and gear as using dirty bombs.  DU are somewhat "edgy" and "special" weapons, but they remain very much conventional, legal, weapons.  Hence any non-conventional response on the part of RU would put it on even shakier footing.  However, the PR advantages of playing up supposed nuclear attributes of DU ammo - i.e. "you don't understand, we're the victims here!" - is certainly something the Kremlin can, and is, doing.  No surprise.

Comment: Do understand that "depleted uranium" is sometimes used as a substitute for lead in "conventional" ammunition.  Uranium is about the same weight as lead and is, in some cases, a little easier to form into bullets, etc.  It also makes bullets which fragment into damaging pieces more effectively.

Comment: Depleted uranium is the _opposite_ of a dirty bomb. It's _less_ radioactive and less able to sustain a nuclear chain reaction than the uranium they dug out of the ground. It's called depleted because it's what's left over after they extracted the uranium isotope needed for nuclear reactor and weapon use.

Comment: @user71659 The radioactivity is similar in the order of magnitude (roughly 3/5 of natural U). It is the fact that uranium is not much radioactive in the first place, not that the depleted ones would be *that* much less radioactive.

Comment: @HotLicks: it's a (better) substitute for tungsten.

Comment: What makes you think the doctrine isn't what Putin says on TV?

Comment: @HotLicks: the more technical term https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staballoy

Comment: @AdamGyenge A dirty bomb is one designed to spread radioativity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_bomb). DU is explictly designed to be less radioactivity (that's the Depleted part). Therefore, DU is specifically not a dirty bomb. While there is still some radioactivity, most things are radioactive (including people!) naturally.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depleted_uranium - it's the sort of thing used to *shield against radioactivity*. It's use in weapons are that it's a -lot- denser than lead. More mass per volume means at the same velocity it's packing a lot stronger punch (68.4% more force), although it requires more force to project it to the same velocity.

Comment: @bharring It is not designed to be less radioactive. Not at all. It is designed to have less isotope useful for the chain reaction. It is also incidentally less radioactive than natural uranium, but not by that much. By less then half. Natural uranium could be used for shielding in a similar way. Natural uranium simply is not that much radioactive to start with.

Answer (score 28):

Well, to flip the question somewhat, Russia fields the [Svinets-2 APFSDS](https://www.icbuw.eu/depleted-uranium-du-and-russian-ammunition/) which ...drumroll... holds DU.

> Russia has further developed its DU munition. According to an article of TASS news agency (based on a statement of the Russian Ministry of Defense), Russian T-80BV tanks are now to be equipped with such high-penetrating ammunition. The article states that tanks of the T-80BV series got the new gun 2А46М-4 with an improved stabilizer and the loading mechanism for the ammunition 3BM59 Svinets-1 and 3BM60 Svinets-2. The ammunition of the type „Svinets“ (English: „lead“) is a part of Russian arsenal since 1991: „Svinets-1“ has a uranium-tungsten carbide core and **„Svinets-2“ uses depleted uranium.**

More [techy info (pdf)](https://community.apan.org/cfs-file/__key/docpreview-s/00-00-13-65-28/2019_2D00_02_2D00_01-Bigger-is-Better_2D00_-The-T_2D00_80BVM-Tank-Modernization-_2800_Bartles_2900_.pdf):

But, let's get it from the horse's mouth, [(2018), Russia’s upgraded T-80BV tank to feature capability of firing depleted uranium shells - Military & Defense - **TASS**](https://tass.com/defense/1036958):

> The information that one of the shells has the depleted uranium core was confirmed to TASS by military expert, Editor-in-Chief of the Arsenal of the Fatherland journal Viktor Murakhovsky. "It has the alloy of the depleted uranium and tungsten," he said, adding that the open sources mentioned it as "the Material B."
>
> **The use of depleted uranium ammunition does not violate any international treaties, the expert said.**

To bring this back to the question.  DU ammunition, is very much part of Russia's *conventional* weapons doctrine, since they deploy it in that role themselves (DU is used for its [ballistic and armor penetration properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depleted_uranium#Military_applications), not because of "nuclear stuff").

How they will react to the use of NATO-supplied DU shells can't be answered at this point since it would be purely speculative.  Consider this another one of the Kremlin's red lines, for whatever that is worth.  However, they will have a hard time convincing anyone sitting on the fence of their good faith if they retaliate with nuclear/chemical weapons because of it:  DU is considered as conventional, if controversial, armaments by most countries, *including themselves*.  Not as "dirty bombs".

Also, keep in mind that, while countries may have contingency plans to handle dirty bomb events, those would, *I assume*, typically be concerned with terrorist attacks.  Dirty bombs don't make all that much sense in the context of high intensity conventional war, so expecting "doctrine" covering those circumstances, and us knowing about it, is unrealistic.

Comment: BTW, both the US and the USSR researched and tested prototypes of such "dirty bomb" weapons (more properly called radiological weapons [RW]) in the 1950s, but concluded they were pointless/inferior [next] to chemical or nuclear [explosion] weapons for area denial https://doi.org/10.1162/isec_a_00391 The two countries then even proposed a draft to ban RWs in the late 1970s, but "Notwithstanding
agreement between Moscow and Washington, however, the initiative
foundered over scope and definitional issues, and because of the low
priority most delegations attached to the subject."

Comment: *How they will react to the use of NATO-supplied DU shells can't be answered...* - RT has an article [EU warns of response to Belarus nuclear move](https://www.rt.com/russia/573635-borrell-sanctions-belarus-nuclear/) that answers this: *Russian President Vladimir Putin revealed on Saturday that tactical nuclear weapons will arrive in Belarus as early as this summer. Putin said that he made the decision after the UK announced it would transfer toxic depleted uranium munitions to Ukraine, a move he described as “absolute recklessness.”*

Comment: First, how they'd react couldn't be answered when the question was asked:  your article is more recent.  Second, it still can't be answered:  stationing nukes in Belarus does not change things all that much.  Germany [hosts US nukes](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/10/26/u-s-plans-upgraded-nukes-europe-00063675) under much the same terms.  It's a political message, but that's about it:  a *real* reaction would involve some form of military escalation by Russia and that's an entirely different kettle of fish.  We'll see it when if/when it happens.

Comment: The answer is quite clear - it's both a threat and a message. Along with Finland's ratification of NATO membership and UK willingness to supply DU weaponry Russia is sending a very political message to NATO that Russia is very prepared to use the nuclear option if they continue to supply Ukraine with more lethal weapons to prolong the war or diminish Russia's military capability. This is bound to make Europe more jittery.

Answer (score -7):

It doesn't matter what their official policy is. It only matters what they try to sell to the rest of the world.

They showed their little kidnapped children to try and sway the world into thinking they are the good guys.  The ICC slapped Putin with war crimes.  PR message gone terribly wrong :-D. Does this seem like a rational stance?

Why would they not portray DU shells as a nuclear attack to justify their own nuclear response?  Too often we get hung up in the words people say and official written policies because we feel like they are being rational and they can be reasoned with.  They've been attacking Ukraine for more than 12 months for no rational reason.  Why do they need one to justify an escalation?

Just like the US attacked Korea and Vietnam to "deter communism" and overthrew countless Latin governments for the same reason.  Those weren't rational decisions nor rationally justified.  But the fed the US public their "rational" justification (if they even let them know it was going on).

The question misses the point because it assumes Russia is doing this for rational reasons.  And they aren't.  Maybe they feel like they are being rational, but so did the US.  But clearly to a neutral 3rd party both aggressors were out of their mind.